# How to create fog effect over specific tiles in dungeon game

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, shaders, sprites

I'm working on a game in unity and I have areas the player cannot enter blocked off by game objects that are animated sprites that are supposed to look like fog. They don't look that great and I'd like to try something a little more complex, but as a beginner with Unity I don't know where to start.

I'd like to make a fog effect that surrounds the tiles that are blocked ([Similair to this asset I found](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/fullscreen-camera-effects/simple-2d-fog-storm-smoke-115617). But I only want it to be seen over specific tiles.)

I also looked into something like a darkness emitting light, but haven't found anything that works.

[image: Game Explination]

Here is a picture of the scene hierarchy.

[image: Unity Scene Hierarchy]

Comment: Best would be if you could provide a screenshot of your current game to get a better picture. Surrounds means for me not on the tile but all others, but probably you want it on each tile that can't be accessed, right? Should the fog be animated or just look like fog?

Comment: I was thinking a radius slightly bigger than the tile itself on top of it. I don't know if its the right solution because I can't find anything similar online, but I was thinking of somehow making the foggy tiles into a single mesh and having the fog animate over it. @Zibelas

Comment: The screenshot helps a lot, I was thinking opposite, fog would be on unvisited tiles. How about spawning a fog tile on top of it with some transparency? Each move just leaves a tile behind and they connect automatically together.

Comment: I'm going to try a handmade animation, but ideally it would be a single animation that spans the entire area, instead of a bunch of copy pasted sprite animations @Zibelas